# Excel, making a column into time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hopefully this is something simple, i have been logging some data in which time is needed. I have logged every second so the data has come out like this:

[image]

this goes upto 5320 (seconds), so if i wanted to change the column to start from 13:00 (this is when i started the test so lets say 1 second is that time) how would i change all of that data to the time from that point?

i really hope that makes sense to someone!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the TIME function:

```
 =TIME(13,0,A2)
```

[image]

If 1 second is equivalent to 13:00:00 and not 13:00:01 then do

```
 =TIME(13,0,A2-1)
```

Comment: you are getting quicker.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks!